# How to select Postgres schema with reactive datasource in Quarkus

Tags: postgresql, reactive, quarkus

I am trying to select a non-default PostgreSQL schema when using a reactive datasource with Quarkus.
I tried a syntax similar to the working "regular", non-reactive datasource using `?currentSchema`:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host/database?currentSchema=int
```

like follows:

```
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://host/database?currentSchema=int
```

However, it does not have any effect, the default schema is always used.

How can I achieve selecting a PostgreSQL schema for a reactive datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. As a workaround I helped myself by changing the search_path for the user:

```
ALTER ROLE readonly IN DATABASE "quarkus"
    SET search_path TO newSchema;
```

Comment: I created an altogether different database instead of just using a different schema within the same database, as this is somewhat cleaner to my use-case and has better IDE tooling support anyway